# Guidance on how to index Elasticsearch documents using Spring Data

Tags: spring, elasticsearch, spring-data, spring-data-elasticsearch

My application uses both Spring Data JPA and Spring Data Elasticsearch.

I plan to first persist the JPA entities, then map them to a slightly different java class (the Elasticsearch document) and finally index that document into the Elasticsearch index.

However, I have a few questions as how, where and when to index the documents.

- Is indexing a time consuming process that should be asynchronous?
- What design pattern could help me avoid having problematic code such as the following?

`saveAdvertisement` method from `AdvertisementService`:

```
public void saveAdvertisement(Advertisement jpaAdvertisement) {
        jpaAdvertisementRepository.save(jpaAdvertisement);
        //somehow map the jpa entity to the es document 
        elasticSearchTemplate.index(esAdvertisement);
}
```

whereby I have to have two concerns in the same method:

1. JPA persist
2. Elasticsearch indexing

Comment: I would strongly recommend that you do not couple the 2 concerns by using for example some kind of observer pattern which is fairly straight forward with Spring. Instead of hard coding the indexing stuff into the the service it is more flexible to make an abstraction by just sending an event. Introduce an `ApplicationEventPublisher` into the service and each service method that modifies a domain object is using it to notify others about that modification:
`publisher.publishEvent(new AdvertisementCreatedEvent(jpaAdvertisement)`. By doing so, any listener can register for such an event and act.